# Как найти количество положительных в массиве в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Всем привет! Нашел такую задачу:

Задан массив из 10 элементов BYTE. Найти количество положительных.

Как это можно реализовать в ассемблере?

Comment: Хм.. А байты знаковые? А то это, 10...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так (встроенный ассемблер в Delphi):

```pascal
var
  a: array of int8;
  cnt: integer;
begin
  a := [3,1,0,-2,100, 40,0,-4,44,1];

  asm
      mov edx, a 
      xor eax, eax
      mov ecx, 10
    @@start:
      cmp byte ptr[edx], 0
      jle @@pass
      inc eax
    @@pass:
      inc edx
      loop @@start
      mov cnt, eax
  end;

  Caption := IntToStr(cnt) 
 // 6
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо!